# XSLT apply attribute depending on position

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I am using XSLT for a website based on the 960 grid css framework.

I have columns of divs that span across the page if it is the first div in a row it should have a class first applied, if it is the middle one then no class and if it is the 3rd in the row it should have the class last applied.

I am really scratching my head as the best way to go about this any help is appreciated.

Below is the structure I want to end up with, the numbers inside the divs represent the position.

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div id="main-content" class="alpha grid_12" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="grid_4 alpha">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4 ">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4 omega">
            3
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4 alpha">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't like umbraco questions as they are far of standar XSLT... But I can tell you that you want something with the `mod` operator: when $position mod 3 = 1 then alpha, when $position mod 3 = 0 then omega...

Comment: Thanks, would you not put an answerin so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:classes>
  <class class="omega"></class>
  <class class="alpha"></class>
  <class/>
 </my:classes>

 <xsl:variable name="vClasses" select=
  "document('')/*/my:classes/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@id='main-content']/div">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos123" select=
    "1 + (position() mod 3)"/>
  <div class="{@class} {$vClasses[$vPos123]/@class}">

   <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "node()|@*[not(name()='class')]"/>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document**:

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div id="main-content" class="alpha grid_12" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <div class="grid_4">
                     1
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4 ">
                     2
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4">
                     3
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4">
                     4
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<div class="container_12">
   <div id="main-content" class="alpha grid_12" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <div class="grid_4 alpha">
                     1
        </div>
      <div class="grid_4  ">
                     2
        </div>
      <div class="grid_4 omega">
                     3
        </div>
      <div class="grid_4 alpha">
                     4
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The identity rule copies every node "as-is",** unless overridden.
2. **A template overrides the identity rule for elements of the kind `div[@id='main-content']/div`**
3. **The expression `1 + (position() mod 3)` maps the position into the set {2, 3, 1}.**
4. **The above expression is used as an index** into the children of the globally specified `<my:classes>` element to extract the new CSS class to be added to the `div` element